How to make multiplexer with functions?
My assignment is to create a multiplexer given a table.   So far, this is what I have. A and B are 4-bit inputs via toggle switch, S is the MUX controller, Cin is a carry-in that we assign a toggle switch to, F is an output that goes to a seven segment display, and Cout is the carry output that is displayed by an LED.
module ALU_4bits (
    input [3:0] S,  
    input Cin,       
    input [3:0] A, B,    
    output reg [3:0] F,  
    output reg Cout    
);

    always @(*) begin
        Cout = 0;
        case ({S, Cin})
            5'b00000: {Cout, F} = A + B;              
            5'b00001: {Cout, F} = A + B + 1;     
            5'b00010: {Cout, F} = A + ~B;         
            5'b00011: {Cout, F} = A + ~B + 1;       
            5'b00100: {Cout, F} = -A;                
            5'b00101: {Cout, F} = A + 1;  
            5'b00110: {Cout, F} = B - 1;      
            5'b00111: {Cout, F} = A;         
            5'b01000: F = A & B;                 
            5'b01001: F = A | B;                 
            5'b01010: F = ~A;                        
            5'b01011: F = A ^ B;                       
            5'b10000: F = A >>> 1;                     
            5'b10001: F = A << 1;                     
            5'b10010: F = {A[2:0], A[3]};              
            5'b10011: F = {A[0], A[3:1]};            
            default: F = 4'b0000;                    
        endcase
    end
endmodule

I am in a digital logic class and I have no clue how to write Verilog. Currently I am trying to debug the first case, but I am unsure where to start. The adder works properly until you add two of the same numbers (ex. 1000+1000 gives the output 0100 with no carry). It is my understanding that when using always @(*) begin it does bitwise operations? So no need for adders and I can instead preform a+b where a and b are 4-bit busses.
I have not even tried to debug the other ones yet since I can't even figure the first step out.

The code you posted works as expected when I run a simulation.
There may be a bug with your simulation software, or there may be a bug in your testbench code.
You can run the simulation on EDA Playground to see that it gives you the output you expect.  It shows F=0 and Cout=1 when A and B are 'b1000.
Here is the testbench I used:
module tb;
    bit [3:0] A;
    bit [3:0] B;
    bit Cin;
    bit [3:0] S;
    wire Cout;
    wire [3:0] F;

ALU_4bits dut (
    .A     (A),
    .B     (B),
    .Cin   (Cin),
    .S     (S),
    .Cout  (Cout),
    .F     (F)
);

initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    #5;
    A = 3;
    B = 2;
    #5;
    A = 'b1000;
    B = 'b1000;
    #5 $finish;
end
endmodule


Thank you! It may be a bug in my display driver/me not knowing how to properly test my circuit.
